# HandsOnTable cell content overflow

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I was maybe sloppy while searching the HOT documentation, but I haven't found any way to define how the overflow text inside a cell should be displayed.

Is there any way to display the text over the cell width if next cells are empty?

Another thing I also did not found using the documentation is an option to retain column widths and height while pasting copied content. Currently width and height are not copied.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is using the `wordWrap` option. [From the documentation](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.4.0/Options.html#wordWrap):

> `wordWrap` (Boolean)
>
> When set to true, the text of the cell content is wrapped if it does not fit in the fixed column width.
>
> Since:
>
> - 0.11.0
>
> Default Value:
>
> - true